# How to avoid RStudio writing temp files to SSD?

Tags: r, rstudio, hard-drive

I have RStudio and R installed in my SSD with only 13 GB of empty space left. The problem is that when I launch some demanding algorithm with RStudio, it quickly fills my SSD with some temporary files that are quit huge, probable because of 16 GB RAM I have in my computer. However, I also have 1 TB almost empty hard disk in the same computer. Is it possible to reroute those temp files to hard disk? Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: You're likely to get faster RStudio-specific answers here https://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: However, you could try setting `TMPDIR` explicitly in your `~/.Renviron` to see if it will use the hard disk (as that is likely where it and R are putting the temp files). `TMP` and `TEMP` are also env vars you may want to set to said alternate path

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, setting TMPDIR, TMP and TEMP values have not solved the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you set the temp directory for Rstudio correctly?

Comment: When I type Sys.getenv("TEMP") in command prompt it gives me the path that I have set.